# TI TLV320DAC32 vs TLV320DAC33

Tags: linux, texas-instruments

A board I'm working on has been populated with a TI TLV320DAC32 sound codec.  My target O/S is Linux and quickly looking in sound/soc/codecs I see support for the TLV320DAC**33**.

Octopart, DigiKey, even TI's website make no mention of the -33, just the -32.

Does anyone know why there's a difference here?  Was the -33 made for Nokia (I'm guessing since they did the driver) but the -32 is the one for general purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a Nokia service manual for the 5610, which uses the TLV320AC33.

Here -> [[http://mastermobile.spb.ru/service/nokia_5610_rm-242_service_schematics.pdf][1]](http://mastermobile.spb.ru/service/nokia_5610_rm-242_service_schematics.pdf%5d%5b1%5d)

based on the pin numbering in this schematic, the TLV320DAC33 uses a ball grid array package while the -32 device used a QFN32 package.

Waltx

Comment: @zydeco100, can TLV320DAC32 be worked with TLV320DAC33 driver present Linux tree ?

Answer (score 0):

According Linux header file: "tlv320dac33.h" and TLV320DAC32 datasheet - those two devices are no compatible on registers level. In same time There is support of other TI codec in Linux kernel - "tlv320aic32.h","tlv320aic32.c", this codec almost pin-to-pin compatible with tlv320dac32 and also those devices compatible  on register level - the only difference:

tlv320aic32 - is full codec (has ADC and DAC inside - i.e. has audio input and output)...

When
tlv320dac32 - has DAC only (audio output, but no audio input).